# Calculating the next leap year from input in python

Tags: python

In my course, I'm supposed to write a program which takes input as a year and return its following leap year. I already wrote the condition if user input is already a leap year, but I'm unable to write logic if the user input is not a leap year.

Thankful for any tips!

```
year = int(input("Give year:"))
leap = year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 ==0

if leap:
    print(f"The next leap year from {year} is {year + 4}")
# what next?
```

Comment: Why do you feel there is a need for a while loop? You prompt the user for input, they give a year, and you return a value.

Comment: I guess you should go over [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to get the basics of loops and such

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using while loop like this

```
inp_year = int(input("Give year:"))
year = inp_year
leap = year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 ==0

if leap:
   print(f"The next leap year from {year} is {year + 4}")

while not leap:
    year += 1
    leap = year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 ==0
print(f"The next leap year from {inp_year} is {year}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, python does not have a `do while` option, but you can use a `while` loop like this:

```
year = int(input("Give year:"))
original = year
leap = year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 ==0

while not leap:
    year += 1
    leap = year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 ==0

print(f"The next leap year from {original} is {year}")
```

Comment: sorry, you are right. I've already corrected it. Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function:

```
def find_leap(year, first):
    if not first and ((year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0)):
        return year
    else:
        return find_leap(year+1, False)

year = int(input("Give year: "))
print("The next leap year from", year, "is", find_leap(year, True))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the 3 solutions here but they don't work with century year. for example the next leap year following 1896, should be 1904 and not 1900 since 1900 is not dividable by 400.
This code was tested and accepted for the exercise "The next Leap year" in part 2 of Python programming MOOC 2021 by the University of Helsinki where you can find also the official model solution.

```py
year = int(input("Year: "))

initial = year

while True:

    year += 1

    if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 and year % 400 != 0):
        break

    elif year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0:
        break

print(f"The next leap year after {initial} is {year}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yr = int(input("Year: "))
new = yr

while True:
    new += 1
    if (new % 4 == 0 and new % 100 != 0) or new % 400 == 0:
        break
print(f"The next leap year after {yr} is {new}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

With nested conditions:

```
year = int(input("Year: "))
leap = year

while True:
    leap += 1
    if leap % 100 == 0:
        if leap % 400 == 0:
            break
    elif leap % 4 == 0:  
        break
        
print(f"The next leap year after {year} is {leap}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the model solution for the 2023 course.

```
start_year = int(input("Year: "))

year = start_year + 1

while True:

    if year % 100 == 0:
        if year % 400 == 0:
            break
    elif year % 4 == 0:
        break
 
    year += 1
 
print(f"The next leap year after {start_year} is {year}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is getting a little confusing because in fact you don't have to check if the year you input is a leap year or not, you just have to increment the input by 1 until you find a year that matches the conditions of being a leap year. Here's my code for the same exercise. I hope it helps :)

```
# Write your solution here
year = int(input("Year:"))
next_leap_year = year + 1
while True:
    if next_leap_year % 4 == 0 and next_leap_year % 100 == 0:
        if next_leap_year % 400 == 0:
            print(f"The next leap year after {year} is {next_leap_year}") 
            break
        else:
            next_leap_year = next_leap_year + 4
            print(f"The next leap year after {year} is {next_leap_year}")
            break
    elif next_leap_year % 4 == 0:
        print(f"The next leap year after {year} is {next_leap_year}")
        break
    else:
        next_leap_year += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
year1 = int(input("Year:"))
year = year1
while True:
    year + =  1
    if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year %400 == 0):
        leapyear = True
        break

    else:
        leapyear = False
        #print(f" {year} is not leap year")   
 
print(f" The next leap year after {year1} is {year}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
inp_year = int(input("Year:"))
year = inp_year
leap = False
while not leap:
    year += 1
    leap = year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 ==0
    #print (year, leap)
print(f"The next leap year after {inp_year} is {year}")
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).